# OkHttp no Android conecta no meu server websocket porém não reflete as mensagens emitidas

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, kotlin, websocket

Seguindo esta documentação https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ criei um pequeno projeto spring capaz de emitir mensagens em tempo real usando websockets, a parte web fica desta maneira

[image: tela que emite as mensagens através de um websocket]

até aqui tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema começa quando tento conectar um app Android simples de uma única tela que deveria exibir as mensagens emitidas pela plataforma web, esta conexão está sendo feita usando OkHttp, abaixo explico como funciona essa conexão.

[image: tela do app que exibe as mensagens]

Ao clicar no botão start a conexão com o server é feita e é exibido o primeiro texto dizendo que a conexão foi realizada com sucesso, este é o código do layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Start !"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/start"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Em seguida temos o código da Activity onde a conexão é de fato realizada

```
package br.com.brendoniwata.websocketconnectiontest

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.*
import okio.ByteString

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var client: OkHttpClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        client = OkHttpClient()

        start.setOnClickListener {
            start()
        }

    }

    private fun start() {
        val request = Request.Builder().url("ws://192.168.42.26:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket").build()
        val listener = EchoWebSocketListener()
        client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
    }

    private fun output(txt: String) {
        runOnUiThread {
            output.text = "${output.text}\n\n$txt".trimIndent()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
    }

    inner class EchoWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            output("connection established")
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            output("Receiving : $text")
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, byte: ByteString) {
            output("Receiving : ${byte.hex()}")
        }

        override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
            output("Closing : $code / $reason")
        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            output("Erro : ${t.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no botão start é chamado o método start() que basicamente inicia a conexão websocket com o servidor, esta conexão ocorre com sucesso, porém quando vou na plataforma web e começo a inserir mensagens o aplicativo não está refletindo as mensagens inseridas da forma como deveria.
Para dirimir maiores dúvidas irei deixar também o código do meu controller, onde está presente o mapeamento da request feita pela página web e o mapeamento do envio da mensagem ao cliente.

```
package com.example.messagingstompwebsocket;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }

}
```

Aqui no controller basicamente a requisição é feita para /hello e redicionada para os clients registrados como /topic/greetings

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não tenho muita experiência com websockets em android, mas lendo a documentação do back em Spring que você mencionou, ela relata que:

> STOMP is a subprotocol operating on top of the lower-level WebSocket.

Então *talvez* o OkHttp não tenha suporte pra essa comunicação em específico. Também, analisando o código não consegui encontrar a parte de inscrição nos topics que você mencionou (topics/greetings), o que parece ser bem importante pra essa comunicação.

Procurando um pouco vi que o pessoal costumar utilizar a lib [StompProtocolAndroid](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid). No repo também tem um [caso de uso de como implementar](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid/tree/master/example-client).

Só os exemplos de uso (na parte do android) encontrados no repositório já esclarecem minhas dúvidas em relação ao seu código:

```
private StompClient mStompClient;
 
 // ...
 
 mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/example-endpoint/websocket");
 mStompClient.connect();
  
 mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
     Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
 });
  
 mStompClient.send("/topic/hello-msg-mapping", "My first STOMP message!").subscribe();
  
 // ...
 
 mStompClient.disconnect();
```

Tem uma questão aqui que pode te ajudar também: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675194/is-it-possible-to-use-stomp-with-okhttp3-websocket

Espero ter ajudado e se você encontrar a solução, não deixa de informar pra gente. Abraços ;)